# [deezer][android] Facebook Login "Unexpected url" with SDK v0.10.18

Tags: android, facebook, deezer

I'm using deezer SDK v1.10.18 for Android, and whenever I try to connect with a Facebook account, after filling the login form and being asked to share messages on Facebook, my app receive an "Unexpected URL" error while the browser opens to display some page on deezer.com.

I've tried the v1.10.18 especially to solve the "Unexpected URL" bug, since it's said in the release notes that it is supposed to be fix in this version, but while it does go a little further on the process, it still doesn't work.
Is their something to be done or is the SDK still broken?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The facebook connect feature is still broken in 0.10.18, It will be fixed in the next version.

Comment: Ok thank you for the confirmation. Any clue on when should the next version be released?

Comment: The 0.10.19 version is now available.